# how to validate unix command with java

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am writing a java program that takes command and run it in unix shell. I have managed to get the output, but I need the program to detect if the given command is invalid, now, if I put in an invalid command, it gives me an error. Otherwise, it's working fine. Can anybody help me with this?? Here is my code:

```
public class TestCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestCommand obj = new TestCommand();
        String sentence ="";
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (sentence != " ")
        {
             if (sentence !="exit")
             {   
                 System.out.println("> ");
                 sentence = scn.nextLine();

                 String outPut = obj.executeCommand(sentence);
                 System.out.println(outPut + "\n");
             }
             else
             {
                 System.exit(2);
             }
        }




    }

    private String executeCommand(String sentence)
    {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();


        Process p;

        try
        {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sentence);
            p.waitFor();

            BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bfrd.readLine())!= null)
            {
                output.append(line);

            }
            bfrd.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not directly on point, but don't test `String` equality with `==` or `!=`. You should be using something like `!sentence.equals(" ")` and `!sentence.equals("exit")`

Comment: You are trying to determine if the shell command you are given is a syntactically valid shell command? So `echo foo bar` is ok but `echo 'foo` is not?

Comment: Try checking the exitValue? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()

Answer (score 4):

Unix shell language is extraordinarily complex.  Re-implementing enough of it in java to test for correctness would be a large undertaking.  If you just want to find out if some shell code is *syntactically* correct, you can use `bash` with the `-n` option:

```
bash -n file_with_code_to_test
```

Or:

```
bash -n -c string_with_code_to_test
```

The key thing here is the `-n` option.  It tells `bash` to read the commands and check their syntax *without* executing them.  Thus, this is safe to run.

You can run these command from `java` just as you would other `bash` commands.

`bash` will return an exit code of `0` if the code is syntactically correct.  If it isn't, it will print error messages and return an exit code of `1`.

Just to be clear, this checks *syntax*.  It will, for example, *not* test for the existence of needed files or commands, only that the code is would run if they did exist.